# Can logistic equation explode in a finite time?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

**Exercise**

Solve $$y''-5y'+3y = 2-10x+3x^2$$. Is solution stable?
The initial conditions are $y(0)= 0 $ $y'(0)=0$

**My solution:**

So first we solve homogeneous part:

$y''-5y'+3y = 0 \Rightarrow \lambda^2-5\lambda+3\lambda = 0$

$$\lambda_{1,2} = \frac{5+/- \sqrt{13}}{2}$$

Hence $y_H = \alpha_1e^{\frac{5+ \sqrt{13}}{2}}+\alpha_2e^\frac{5- \sqrt{13}}{2}$

I will guess the particular solution :

$$y_P = Ax^2+Bx+C$$

After calculations i got that $y_P=x^2$

Hence $y= \alpha_1e^{\frac{5+ \sqrt{13}}{2}x}+\alpha_2e^{\frac{5- \sqrt{13}}{2}x} + x^2$

Now we put the initial conditions in:

And this is where i am stuc. I cannot find values of $\alpha_1 , \alpha_2$.

**My question**

Did i have some mistakes until this point? If not, can someone please help me to find $\alpha_1 , \alpha_2$?

And solution is not stable since $Re(\lambda_1,\lambda_2) > 0$, right?

Comment: You forgot $x $ in exponent.

Comment: Factors of $x$ are missing in the exponents.

Comment: Yes i forgot by the accident,sorry

Comment: So there is not mistake until now?

Comment: What about the stability of the solution?

Comment: The solution is not stable, and your rationale is correct.  If the real parts of $\lambda_1, \lambda_2 > 0$ small perturbations in initial conditions will turn into large differences over time.  As far as $a_1,a_2$ go, that should be fairly simple.  $a_1 + a_2 = 0$ and $(5+\sqrt {13}) a_1 + (5-\sqrt {13}) a_2 = 0$ is a system of linear equations.

Comment: Just from looking at the equation, you see that there's always going to be a particular solution in the form of a quadratic. It doesn't matter what the other constants are, the solution will not be bounded

Comment: So it means that this equation will explode in a finite time? Could you please explain better why?

Comment: You're messing up two different concepts, namely **instability**, and **explosion in finite time**, I'm afraid. As you and other people have shown, the solution (in fact, *any* solution) is unstable. But it is a fact from a (good) standard course in ODEs that any solution of a linear ODE is defined as long as the coefficients are defined, so there cannot be explosion in finite time. Incidentally, your title doesn't fit the question: logistic equations are of the form $y'=ay(1-y/b)$, for $a>0$ and $b>0$.